# How to use wsdl in servicemethod?

Tags: spring-mvc, soap, wsdl

I am new to **soap web-services**. I have wsdl file configured in pom.xml like below:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>http://www.webservic.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
          </wsdlUrls>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I want to use this webservice in spring mvc application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can follow this guide for [Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) on Spring.io.
2. I prefer following way of consuming web service in Spring. You can inspire yourself. (Note that for generating POJO classes from WSDL I use Eclipse IDE > Generate classes using JAXB).

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Test WSDL</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test-request-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test-request-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

test-request-ws-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

    <sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" />
    <sws:static-wsdl id="testRequestWS" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/test.wsdl" />

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.test.request.TestRequest" />
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.test.response.TestResponse" />
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
    <name>Your project</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

TestEndpoint.java

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.test.request.TestRequest;
import com.test.response.TestResponse;

@Endpoint
public class TestEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://test.com/wsdl-namespace", localPart = "testRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public TestResponse test(@RequestPayload TestRequest request) {
        final TestResponse res = new TestResponse();
        res.setId(1);
        return res;
    }

}
```